# How can I get daily web traffic data for years in a website

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, releasing-data

Recently I'm doing some research on holiday effect's on web traffic data and trying to predict it more precisely using data in previous year. I need to get daily or hourly web traffic data in a website for years. I only need some data like in 2020/08/03 page:[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) get 50 requests.

I have already get similar data from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/web-traffic-time-series-forecasting/data) and [wikipedia's pageview](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-ez/), and use its [api](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Analytics/AQS/Pageviews) to get hourly pageview data for every day from 2016 to 2020. However, my supervisor didn't think my job can work well on other websites. He thinks all my work is based on wikipedia's pageview data and holiday effects doesn't influence the behavior of a wiki.

So I try to find out more data like e-commerce website's pageview or other websites, but I failed. Is there any datas or logs that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's proper, but this question can go to an end cause I found two wonderful datasets. I'd like to publish them under this answer to help people in similar situation like me.

The first is [Website Analytics Daily Page Views](https://opendata.dc.gov/datasets/acdcbf4dd2c9479abe3a24c8edff93f3?selectedAttribute=2008_PAGEVIEWS) from Open data DC, it contains daily pageview data from 2008 to 2020.

Second is from [City Website Google Analytics](https://performance.ci.janesville.wi.us/Government/City-Website-Google-Analytics/xeqs-kevn), it's a daily pageview data since November 2011 until now.

Many thanks to those who publish pageview data to the public. And if anyone have similar pageview data, please answer this question to let me know it.